# Swift func - Does not conform to protocol "Boolean Type"

Tags: function, swift, dictionary

Yes it's man vs compiler time and the compiler winning yet again!
In the func getRecordNumber I am returning a Bool and a Dictionary

```
func getRecordNumber(recordNumber: Int32) -> (isGot: Bool, dictLocations: Dictionary <String, Double>)
...
return (isGot, dictLocations)
```

However after I have called the func and question the Boolean isGot return I get the error message

```
(isGot: Bool, dictLocations: Dictionary <String, Double>) Does not conform to protocol "Boolean Type"
```

Any ideas what I have left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add parameters into return like this `(isGot: Bool, dictLocations: Dictionary <String, Double>)`. you just need to tell compiler that what type this function will return.

Here is the correct way to achieve that:

```
func getRecordNumber(recordNumber: Int32) -> (Bool, Dictionary <String, Double>)
{
    let isGot = Bool()
    let dictLocations = [String: Double]()

    return (isGot, dictLocations)
}
```